# NOT LIKE does not work with JOIN in wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have this sql query in wordpress with php

```
        $sql = "SELECT last_update.post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} last_update";
        $sql .= " JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS post ON last_update.post_id = post.ID";

        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare(" WHERE {$time} - last_update.meta_value > {$ttl} AND last_update.meta_key = %s", Importer::META_LAST_UPDATE);
        


        if (SyncConfig::getInstance()->option('published_only'))
            $sql .= " AND post.post_status = 'publish'";

        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare(" ORDER BY last_update.meta_value ASC LIMIT %d", self::getProductLimit());

        $product_ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql);

        shuffle($product_ids);
        error_log(print_r( $product_ids, true ));
```

What I want is to skip the results with a "NOT LIKE" for the wildcard result "Product data not found"

Normally I would do something like this

```
        $sql = "SELECT last_update.post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} last_update";
        $sql .= " JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS post ON last_update.post_id = post.ID";
        
        //QUITAR PRODUCTOS CON DATA NOT FOUND
        $sql .= " JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS _ety_product_info ON last_update.post_id = _ety_product_info.post_id";


        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare(" WHERE {$time} - last_update.meta_value > {$ttl} AND last_update.meta_key = %s", Importer::META_LAST_UPDATE);
        
        //QUITAR PRODUCTOS CON DATA NOT FOUND
        $sql .= " AND _ety_product_info.meta_value NOT LIKE '%Product data not found%'";


        if (SyncConfig::getInstance()->option('published_only'))
            $sql .= " AND post.post_status = 'publish'";

        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare(" ORDER BY last_update.meta_value ASC LIMIT %d", self::getProductLimit());

        $product_ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql);

        shuffle($product_ids);
        error_log(print_r( $product_ids, true ));
```

But it gives wrong data.
The strangest thing is that if I remove the "NOT LIKE" and just leave it on "LIKE" it works delivering the expected result if the "_ety_product_info" column contains the value "Product data not found"

What am I doing wrong?
I want to exclude with "NOT LIKE" but it doesn't work.

Apparently this error only happens when I do the "JOIN"

Note: To identify the changes made in the original code with the edited one, just search for: `//QUITAR PRODUCTOS CON DATA NOT FOUND`

**The final query**
`$sql` it would be this:

```
SELECT last_update.post_id
FROM wp_postmeta last_update
JOIN wp_posts AS post ON last_update.post_id = post.ID
JOIN wp_postmeta AS _ety_product_info ON last_update.post_id = _ety_product_info.post_id
WHERE 1659698743 - last_update.meta_value > 86400
AND last_update.meta_key = '_ety_last_update' 
AND _ety_product_info.meta_value NOT LIKE '%Product data not found%' 
AND post.post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY last_update.meta_value ASC LIMIT 17
```

I also tried this but it didn't work.

```
$wild = '%';
$find = 'Product data not found';
$like = $wild . $wpdb->esc_like( $find ) . $wild;
$sql .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND _ety_product_info.meta_value NOT LIKE %s", $like);
```

Comment: To troubleshoot this, do `print_r( $sql )`; right before `get_col()` and see what query you have. And, please [edit] your question to show it.  And  read about [$wpdb->esc_like()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/) for use with LIKE clauses.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the suggestions.
I already edited the question with the final query.

Comment: That same query works with "LIKE" it returns the result of the columns that have the word "Product data not found"
However, I want the opposite, which would be "NOT LIKE" but it doesn't work.

Comment: already tried with "esc_like" i get the same result "NOT LIKE" doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the query you showed us says `NOT LIKE 'Product data not found'`. I guess you want it to say `NOT LIKE '%Product data not found%'` with the `%` wildcard characters.

And, try using LEFT JOIN and putting the NOT LIKE in your ON-condition. In general for readability with these key/value metadata tables it's a good idea to put the key selector in the ON condition. It doesn't matter to the logic for JOINs but it does for LEFT JOINs.

```sql
SELECT last_update.post_id
  FROM wp_postmeta last_update
  JOIN wp_posts AS post
        ON last_update.post_id = post.ID
       AND last_update.meta_key = '_ety_last_update' 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS _ety_product_info 
        ON last_update.post_id = _ety_product_info.post_id
       AND _ety_product_info.meta_value NOT LIKE '%Product data not found%' 
 WHERE 1659698743 - last_update.meta_value > 86400
   AND post.post_status = 'publish' 
 ORDER BY last_update.meta_value ASC 
LIMIT 17
```

This might work for you:  JOIN suppresses the rows from the first table that don't match the second table, but LEFT JOIN keeps them.

This is guesswork. I don't know what other keys are in your metadata tables.

Comment: I did forget to put the wildcards in the example but on the server I did put them. Since google translator removed them. I will try with LEFT JOIN

Comment: With LEFT JOIN I had no luck it delivers the same wrong result.
Apparently it is not taking the value "NOT LIKE"